# Package name conflict issue

Tags: java, package, javaagents

I'm trying to develop a javaagent program, the application incorporates the `log4j` package.

When the user application, e.g tomcat also includes that package, with the same package name, it might be a problem.

Is there a common solution? Other than renaming the `log4j` package name in my javaagent program

Comment: Is it actually a problem?  Your code presumably incorprates the standard Java library, as does Tomcat, and there's no conflict there.  And if you're talking about "duplicate" jars, the apps will only load the jars in their classpath.

Comment: Does your agent "incorporates" or "depends on" `log4j`?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto depends on it

Comment: use a different classpath for your agent